# Trouble with the peak index concept

Tags: real-analysis

so I was reading through Fitzpatrick's advanced calculus, and there is a definition of a peak index $m$ for a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$. We call $m$ a peak index if for all other indices $n$ greater than $m$, $a_{n} \leq a_{m}$. The author then mentions the seemingly obvious fact that a sequence can either have a finite amount of peak indices, or an infinite amount of peak indices.

I was having trouble with understanding how you could have more than one peak index. By our definition, it seems that if you have a peak index, then if you come across a term in the sequence later that is bigger than the value you had at your peak index, then it would override your original peak index.

Just for example, I was looking at a sequence like $\{1,2,3,4,2,3,1,2,4...\}$

It seems like the first 4 in the sequence would be at a peak index, but then later I have another 3 which is certainly bigger than the  next 1 and 2 in the sequence, so are these both peak indices, or is only one of them?

**After posting this, I thought of something else which I was hoping you could confirm. If a sequence has more than one peak index, does that mean that the first peak index sets a threshold value, such that later peak indexes can still be something like a local max, but never larger than the first peak index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence $(a_n)$ has a peak index $c$, then $a_c$ is greater than or equal to all other elements to the right of it (all elements with greater indices). Consider a decreasing sequence. As long as there are no other elements greater than a certain element later in the sequence, then the certain element's index is a peak index. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

A peak index does set the threshold for every peak index after it. You may have many peak indices however after each peak index no peak index after it can be greater than the peak index before it. Peak index just means that every term in the sequence after it is less than that term. So if we are inspecting peak index were are only looking at that peak and after term after it to make sure it's lower, while taking into account that it doesn't violate other peak indices before it.

[please see picture attached for a better idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koeet.jpg)